# Merging two datasets based on inconsistent column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wondering the most parsimonious way to merge datasets based on inconsistent columns.

```
> head(team_measures)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
   team_id geo_entropy job_entropy
   <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 10012         1.79        1.79 
 2 10027         0           1.25 
 3 10044         1.79        0.650
 4 10049         1.00        1.46 
 5 10053         0.811       2.00 


> head(p_calc)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  team.id              p_average
    <int>                <dbl>
1   10000                 4.75
2   10001                 4.98
3   10002                 4.17
4   10003                 4.32
5   10004                 4.22
6   10005                 4.44
```

I am currently doing what feels very hamfisted for such a simple procedure:

```
team_measures <- p_calc %>%
  rename(team_id = team.id) %>%
  select(team_id, p_average) %>%
  left_join(team_measures, by = c('team_id')) %>%
  na.omit()
```

It's actually worse than this, since I get the error:

> ```
> Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : 
>   Can't join on 'team_id' x 'team_id' because of incompatible types (character / integer)
> ```

So I have to recast them to the same type.

Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

dplyr joins have a `by=` argument with a syntax that isn't very intuitive, as `by = c("xxx" = "xxxx")`

```
 full_join(team_measures, p_cal, by = c("team_id" = "team.id") )

   team_id geo_entropy job_entropy p_average
1    10012       1.790        1.79        NA
2    10027       0.000        1.25        NA
3    10044       1.790        0.65        NA
4    10049       1.000        1.46        NA
5    10053       0.811        2.00        NA
6    10000          NA          NA      4.75
7    10001          NA          NA      4.98
8    10002          NA          NA      4.17
9    10003          NA          NA      4.32
10   10004          NA          NA      4.22
11   10005          NA          NA      4.44
```

Comment: Yes! This is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Just change your numeric to character

```
library(tidyverse)
 data.frame(team_id = c("10012", '10027', '10044', '10049','10053'),
       geo_entropy = c(1.79,0,1.79,1.00,0.811),
       job_entropy = c(1.79,1.25,0.650,1.46,2.00)) -> team_measures

data.frame(team.id = 10000:10005,
           p_average = c(4.75,4.98,4.17,4.32,4.22,4.44)) -> p_calc



p_calc %>% 
  mutate(team.id = as.character(team.id)) %>% 
  rename(team_id = team.id) %>% 
  left_join(team_measures)
```

Though this will give you `NA` for `geo_entropy` and `job_entropy` since none of your `team_id` values match.